# React Native ./gradlew assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest fails: "More than one file found with OS independent path"

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, gradlew

I'm running the gradle command: `./gradlew assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest` and it is failing with the following error:

```
> Task :react-native-ffmpeg:mergeDebugAndroidTestNativeLibs FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-ffmpeg:mergeDebugAndroidTestNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'. If you are using jniLibs and CMake IMPORTED targets, see https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#automatic_packaging_of_prebuilt_dependencies_used_by_cmake
```

I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/tanersener/react-native-ffmpeg#6-tips) and added this code to my `build.gradle`:

```
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
    }
```

However, these `packagingOptions` don't seem to make any difference. I should note that running just `assembleRelease` works, it's only when I add in the `assembleAndroidTest` that there are problems. I have an [issue](https://github.com/tanersener/react-native-ffmpeg/issues/187) open on the react-native-ffmpeg github, but this seems like a more general gradle/android issue which is why I'm posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error goes away if you prepend `app:` to the gradle tasks. This is the build command that worked for me: `./gradlew app:assembleRelease app:assembleAndroidTest`.